# New paragraph distance in enumerate

Tags: enumerate

This is the code I'm using :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelindent=0em, listparindent=1em]
\item \kant[1]

New line

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I would like to reduce the distance between the New line and the previous paragraph :

[image]

Comment: Never mind, I just added `\setlength{\parskip}{0em}` and it eliminated the distance.

Comment: @campa No it doesnt, and it's actually the solution I will be using.

Comment: Can you post your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two lengths which can be used in the argument of `enumerate` (when using `enumitem`, of course): `parsep` controls the vertical spacing between paragraphs *within a list item*, and `itemsep` controls the vertical spacing between items. If you want to remove only the paragraph separation in a single item then add `parsep=0pt` to the argument list of `enumerate`

```
\begin{enumerate}[wide,labelindent=0em,listparindent=1em,parsep=0pt]
```

If you want to suppress *both*, you can add `itemsep=0pt` or use the option `noitemsep`, which sets both `parsep` and `itemsep` to zero.